# debugging bundled aurelia errors?

Tags: debugging, runtime-error, bundle, aurelia

I'm getting a blank page and this error when testing my aurelia app.  It worked until I made a bunch of changes and I don't know which one broke it. `vendor-bundle.js:13551` is inside core code. I've got debug messages showing as you can see.Is there a way to find what causes an error like this other than undoing each change one at a time?

`... snipped ...
DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-templating-router.
DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin resources/index.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
vendor-bundle.js:13551 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__useDefault' of undefined
    at ensureOriginOnExports (vendor-bundle.js:13551)
    at vendor-bundle.js:13659
    at Object.execCb (vendor-bundle.js:5432)
    at Module.check (vendor-bundle.js:4620)
    at Module.<anonymous> (vendor-bundle.js:4875)
    at vendor-bundle.js:3873
    at vendor-bundle.js:4925
    at each (vendor-bundle.js:3798)
    at Module.emit (vendor-bundle.js:4924)
    at Module.check (vendor-bundle.js:4675)
    at Module.enable (vendor-bundle.js:4912)
    at Module.init (vendor-bundle.js:4525)
    at callGetModule (vendor-bundle.js:4939)
    at Object.completeLoad (vendor-bundle.js:5347)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (vendor-bundle.js:5453)`

Comment: it seems that the file is located in the resources folder